# Override Eureka config via environment variable in Rancher

Tags: spring-boot, rancher

I have a Spring Boot application deployed in a container on Rancher.
I would like to override the configuration which is in application.yml via the environment variables set on the container in Rancher.
Here is the configuration that I would like to set:

```
eureka:
  instance:
    prefer-ip-address: false
    hostname: fqdn.api.stuff.com
    nonSecurePort: 65230
```

I tried the following equivalents but it doesn't seem to work:

- EUREKA_INSTANCE_PREFERIPADDRESS
- EUREKA_INSTANCE_HOSTNAME
- EUREKA_INSTANCE_NONSECUREPORT

What would be the appropriate spelling ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to use the below names.

```
EUREKA_INSTANCE_PREFER_IP_ADDRESS
EUREKA_INSTANCE_HOSTNAME
EUREKA_INSTANCE_NON_SECURE_PORT
```

Comment: thanks, I finally, got the right spelling, you went a bit faster on stackoverflow :)

Answer (score -1):

You miss two spaces before `instance` in your yaml file, the correct one should be looked like this:

```
eureka:
  instance:
    prefer-ip-address: false
    hostname: fqdn.api.stuff.com
    nonSecurePort: 65230
```

Comment: indeed, I've fixed it but that's not what I'm asking for, I want to override those values via the environment variables in Rancher

Comment: OK, so you want to override those variables after your application started up?

Comment: Spring offers several overriding mechanism, for instance spring.data.elasticsearch.cluster-nodes in your config file can be overridden by providing environment variable SPRING_DATA_ELASTICSEARCH_CLUSTER_NODES